# ScrollSpy with AngularJS not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new at JS and a complete noob at AngularJS.
I implemented an application with navigation bar (later will be added with Angular) and ScrollSpy feature (menu1). That worked great until I added another div (menu2) that shows when I click on the link in menu1. Now scrollspying in menu1 works, but in menu2 it kind of jumps arround. I implemented a function that catches the current element from ScrollSpy and console.logs it. Than I saw that onLoad it logs

"#section1"

"#tema3"

"#tema2"

"#tema1"

and it should log just the #section1.
Even stranger thing happens when I click on "blabla" and open menu2. Then when i press on Tema1, it logs

"#tema3"

"#tema1"

and it should log just the #tema1.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZ6zCkGKuwYAmEGJnxOY?p=preview) of my app.

Any idea of how I can resolve this?
Thanks